# How to extract xml:lang value using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have the HTML tag like:

```
html xmlns = " http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml "  xml:lang=' en-US '  lang='en-US '
```

By using selenium I am getting value of lang attribute, but while retrieving value of xml:lang getting null.

```
htmlTag.getAttribute("lang"); //en-US
htmlTag.getAttribute("xml:lang"); //null
```

Does anyone knows how to get value of `xml:lang`?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if this attribute presents and return `null` if it's not there. As the name indicates, this attribute gives directives for XML documents, you wouldn't find it in the majority of the websites (eg stackoverflow, google, facebook).
Normally you should retrieve it the same way you do for the rest of attributes, eg:

```
String xmlLang = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getAttribute("xml:lang");
```

You can check if an attribute exists with the following method:

```
private static boolean attributeExists(WebElement elem, String attr) {
    return elem.getAttribute(attr) != null;
}
```

Note that for HTML pages, Selenium does not return `null` for a missing `lang` attribute, but it returns an empty `String`. For instance, at the time I am writing this post, [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) does not include the `lang` and `xml:lang` in its served html-source.

But, Selenium will return `null` for `xml:lang` and an empty `String` for `lang`; thus, as a false-positive case, the aforementioned method `attributeExists` will return `true` for a non-existing `lang` attribute.